# videoタグのsrcやsourceにリダイレクトを返すURLを指定できるか？

Tags: html5, 動画, streaming

videoタグのsrcに300などのリダイレクトで本来のビデオソースへのURLを返すURLをセットすることは可能でしょうか？もし可能であれば、CORSなど気をつけるべき点はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

可能です。

HTMLにおけるリソースは原則としてリダイレクトをサポートしています。[(spec)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#fetching-resources) リソースにアクセスが結果がリダイレクトだった場合、ブラウザはリダイレクト先のURLにアクセスして結果を表示します。

注意点として、

1. リダイレクトはHTTPリクエストが2回以上送られるため、パフォーマンスが低下します。
2. アクセス先にリダイレクトループが検出された場合、ブラウザによってリクエストが打ち切られます。

また、リダイレクト先がクロスオリジンなURIである場合は、通常のクロスオリジンのアクセスと同じ注意が必要です。例えば、

1. video要素はクロスオリジンなファイルを再生することができますが、JavaScriptなどから直接データを取得することはできません。
2. video要素のデータをcanvasなどに描画する場合は、[canvasの汚染に注意してください。](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)